# Is this question too trivia or I misunderstand the question. Restriction of the domian of continuous function

Tags: general-topology

$S^1$ is a unit circle and $N := \{ (0,1) \in S^1\}$.

$\phi: S^1 - {N} \to \mathbb{R} $,  $\phi (x_1,x_2) = \frac{x_1}{1-x_2}$.

Show  there does not exist a continuous function $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that we can restrict the domain by $f|_{S^1 - \{N\}} :S^1 - \{N\} \to \mathbb{R},   f|_{S^1 - \{N\}} = \phi$.

It seems very trivia to me. If I assume there is such function. Then, $f(x_1,x_2) = \phi(x_1,x_2) = \frac{x_1}{1-x_2}$. But $f$ is undefined when $x_2=1$

This is the last question from my assignment. It supposed to hard one

Comment: It's not because $\phi$ is not defined that $f$ is not defined... You have that $f=\phi$ where $\phi$ is defined, but that ddoesn't tell you anything where $\phi$ is not defined

Comment: @Tryss, so $f \ne \phi$ if $\phi$ is not defined?. Any hint on how to show properly this $f$ not exists? Will the thought that assume it exists, then use continuity definition lead me to the conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that when you'll approach (0,1) by the left and by the right, you'll get different value, hence you can't be continuous.

Let's parametrize $S^1$ by $S^1 = \{ (\sin(t),\cos(t)) : t \in [-\pi,\pi[\} $

Then define $\tilde{f}(t) = f( \sin(t),\cos(t) )$. You have that $f$ continuous $\Leftrightarrow$ $\tilde{f}$ continuous

Now, you have that

$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \tilde{\phi}(t) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\sin(t)}{1-\cos(t)} = +\infty$$

$$\lim_{t \to 0^-} \tilde{\phi}(t) = \lim_{t \to 0^-} \frac{\sin(t)}{1-\cos(t)} = -\infty$$

So this imply that $\lim_{t \to 0^-} \tilde{f}(t) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{t \to 0^+} \tilde{f}(t) = +\infty$

So $\tilde{f}$ can't be continuous at $0$, and then $f$ can't be continuous at $(0,1)$